# How to print exponential number "m³" using ESC/POS printer with C#?

Tags: c#, encoding, printing, serial-port, escpos

I'm trying to print a ticket, and need to print out m³ as unit of measurement using a serial printer. And the following is what I have tried so far:

```
if (!printer.IsOpen)
    printer.Open();

printer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} m{1}", "2.34", Convert.ToChar(0xB3)));

printer.Close();
```

When I tried to debug and view the value using the text visualizer the text is correct which is "2.34 m³". But when it comes to printing, the text changed to "2.34 m?", where the expected output should be "2.34 m³".

I've been trying to figure this out for days. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: what is the printer class? seems the printer is not supporting the char though, whats the printer model?

Comment: @nalnpir Hello nalnpir. Thanks for the comment. For the printer class, I'm using "System.IO.Ports.SerialPort". And the printer model would be "EP-360C".

Comment: What encoding have you set up in your SerialPort instance? Also, you don't need to use Convert.ToChar just write your superscript 3 directly as all strings in .NET are UTF-16, which is also the reason why you need to setup the proper encoding in your SerialPort instance.

Comment: @ckuri I didn't set up any encoding for the SerialPort instance. So, I'm guessing that I'm using the default encoding provided by the .Net. About setting up the proper encoding, could you please guide me with a few lines of code on how to set up encoding for the printer and which encoding to use. Much appreciated.

Comment: I checked and the default encoding for the SerialPort class is ASCIIEncoding, i.e. a 7-bit encoding which doesn't contain characters like ³ and replaces these with a question mark like you experience. A common 8-bit encoding is ISO-8859-1 which can be setup as follows `printer.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");` which you need to set where you set your other connection settings like port number, baud rate, parity and so on.

Comment: @ckuri Thanks for your advise. I'm gonna try it and keep you posted. Thanks.

Comment: @ckuri I tried it like you suggested. The "?" was changed to "|". Still not printing the "³" word. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: So it seems it uses either [DOS encoding 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Character_set) or [850](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) which has a vertical bar where [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout) has a superscript 3. So the proper setting would be `printer.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(437);` or 850. However, if it’s 437 you are out of luck because this one has no superscript 3, only a superscript 2 and a superscript n. 850 on the other hand has superscript 3.

Comment: I tried both `Encoding.GetEncoding(437)` and `Encoding.GetEncoding(850)`. And none of them is printing out the desired superscript. `Encoding.GetEncoding(850)` got a little closer to printing out the superscript but instead it prints **mⁿ**.

Comment: The superscript n should have also happened with encoding 437 then, because it’s mostly identical 850 except that it contains a superscript n. That aside, like I tried to say in my last comment if a superscript n appears you are of luck, because this means your printer‘s encoding doesn’t support a superscript 3.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know C# well enough to comment on the code in your question, but it's absolutely possible to print the `³` character in ESC/POS by sending `"\x1B\x74\x02\xFC"`.

Here is a picture of a receipt from an Epson TM-T20:

[image: 2.43 m³]

I printed this by using [a PHP library](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php) which understands how to convert UTF-8 into the available code pages of ESC/POS printers. A similar library [exists for python](https://github.com/python-escpos/python-escpos), and you would be well advised to use a C# equivalent if it exists!

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\CapabilityProfile;

$connector = new FilePrintConnector("php://stdout");
$profile = CapabilityProfile::load("default");
$printer = new Printer($connector, $profile);

$printer -> text("2.43 m³\n");
$printer -> cut();
$printer -> close();
```

This corresponds to the following hexdump.

```
$ php superscript-demo.php | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 40 32 2e 34 33 20 6d  1b 74 02 fc 0a 1d 56 41  |.@2.43 m.t....VA|
00000010  03                                                |.|
00000011
```

All of the commands here are:

- `ESC @` - set formatting and character encoding settings back to their defaults.
- `ESC t 2` - select code page 2.
- `LF` - line break
- `ESC V 65 3` - a cut command

The magic here is `ESC t 2`. The code page numbered 2 [on Epson printers](https://mike42.me/escpos-printer-db/#profiles/default) is [legacy code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) [on Epson printers](https://mike42.me/escpos-printer-db/#profiles/default). Other vendors may be different, but the [manual for your printer](https://emaarindia.com/download/Cashino/EP260C-%20360C%20user%20manualV1.0.pdf) also shows CP850 at the same position.

Your default code page (CP437) does not contain the character you want, while in code page 850, `³` is represented by `0xFC`. Once you change code pages, the change is active until you either reset the printer, or issue `ESC @`.

To save time finding special characters individually, you can select a code page which contains everything you plan to use, and then lean on your programming language standard library to encode strings with that code page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if your printer does not support the '³' character natively.
Therefore you need the printer manufacturer's technical manual. There, you must identify a control character sequence for superscript mode and put it in from of a (normal) character '3'. After it, you must switch off superscript mode again.This control codes are printer specific, and you need, therefore you must have this information from the printer manufacturer.

Assuming "Superscript on" is `ESC 0x4e` and "Superscript off" is `ESC 0x4f`, then your cde would look like this:

```
printer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} m{1}3{2}", "2.34", "\x1b\x4e", "\x1b\x4f" );
```

Answer (score 0):

What font are you using?  I think the font you're using doesn't support that character, which is why it put a `?`.  During debug it shows the right character because visual studio is using a font that does support that character.  Try choosing a different font and see if that helps.